# Creating a Large Input Text Field

Tags: google-colaboratory

I have the low tech way of dealing with a large volume of text i.e. `x = """ blah """` but I'd like to use a textbox field like in HTML but I can only find a string input field which appears as only one line. Is there way to get text area?

I'm trying:

```
text_content = "" # @param {type:"string"}
```

But visually I want to dump in a massive amount of text.